# How to handle webview element in robotium?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, robotium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on native app where the one of the page is partially in webview.
Using Uiautomatorviewer the whole webview is highlighting as a whole no inside elements are recognizable.
How to handle this page in robotium?

Answer (score 1):

Now it is supported in latest Robotium i.e. you can use version5.0.

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/

Answer (score 0):

You can download an example test project here:

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/ExampleTestProjects